# How to keep ng-model value even when running validations?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-scope

The topic was heavily discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318495/angularjs-ng-model-value-is-lost-after-custom-validation-directive-is-triggered)

However, there was never addressed any solution as to a general solution to make sure that the ng-model values are not wiped when the validation fails. For me, I find that when it fails, the model has values shown as 'unknown', however this causes the 'key' to be lost so when I do set a valid value, it is not tied to the same instance.

If it makes a difference, I am using the $validators pipeline within a custom attribute for validations.

Answer (score 1):

im not quite sure i get your question but doesnt your problem get resolved with

```
<input type="number" ng-model="xxx" ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }">
```

that way youre telling to the model to keep invalid values inserted in the model in this example that could be text in the number input